# Multiplying two JTextFields to display an answer

Tags: java, netbeans, phpmyadmin

So I have a stock management system designed in NetBeans/Java. 
It looks like this:

[image]

When i click on any of the items in the table, as shown above the text fields auto populate, however I am also looking at getting the total cost of whatever product i click on to also calculate:

What I mean by this is, the above clicked product (ID 6) has 10 units currently in stock, the price is 15, so in the "Total cost of units in stock" field should be the answer (150).

My question is, is there an easy way to do this via the Java Code, for example multiplying the two Jtextfields together? Or is it possible to create another column in my database to calculate the total (if that's even possible) and display it in the desired field?.

Appreciate any help given.

Comment: java code, take two inputs from the jtextfield, convert string to double and multiply it and settext to your desired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, is there an easy way to do this via the Java Code, for
>   example multiplying the two Jtextfields together?

Yes it is easy, As a example:

```
double units = Double.parseDouble(jTextfield1.getText());
double unitPrice = Double.parseDouble(jTextfield2.getText());
double total = units * unitPrice;
jTextfield3.setText(total);
```

> Or is it possible to create another column in my database to calculate
>   the total (if that's even possible) and display it in the desired
>   field?.

Yes, you can do this also but calcuating in java(programatically) is easy than calculating query.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you retrieve the data from the two desired text fields, assign them to two individual Double variables and then apply arithmetic functions to them to get your output.